# How to get host adress in java tomcat server

Tags: java, server, tomcat7, ip-address

I'm trying to get IP address from DNS like this:

```
InetAddress hostAddr = InetAddress.getByName("somentp.server.com");
```

but hostAddr is null,
it seems like it can't find it.
I'm doing this from a thread in Java, which is executed on a ServletContextListener in Tomcat Server.
If i do this from the same thread but in a normal Java app, it works perfectly fine.
The goal of all this is to use the address as argument to  [NTP Client API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/time/TimeTCPClient.html).

I don't know if it's a problem of Tomcat, some configuration or any other bug

I hope you can help me,
thanks

Comment: Surely it throws an exception rather than returning null?

Answer (score 0):

As per the `inetAddress#getByName` [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName-java.lang.String-), the static method `getByName` doesn't return a null unless the method throws one of the two exceptions `UnknownHostException` or `SecurityException`.

Your code in the `ServletContextListener` seems to be swallowing the exception. You need to debug that code and find out which exception out of the above two is being thrown by the call to getByName. Once you determine the exception type, you can take an appropriate action to correct the error reported by that exception. E.g. if the exception is `UnknownHostException`, you might want to check the host name argument that you are passing to the method.